# Why can certain variables in a multiple regression not be included in logarithmic form?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression, regression-coefficients, logarithm

1. I have a multiple regression equation where log(salary) = b0 + b1(ceotenure). What is the purpose of putting the dependent variable in logarithmic form? How would you interpret the change in y for a 1 unit increase in ceotenure?
2. For this multiple regression equation, what are the unit measurements for RMSE?
3. I have a second multiple regression equation where salary = b0 + ln(sales) + ln(marketvalue). How does the fact that the independent variables are now in natural logarithmic form change the interpretation of a 1 unit increase in x leads to a ____ change in y?
4. I am asked to add profits to this second equation. It asks why this variable cannot be included in logarithmic form? I have no idea.

Comment: Because this is a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag to your question. Please take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

1. You would use this model under the assumption that "salary" increases exponentially with "ceotenure". The log-linear form captures this relationship. For a 1 unit increase in "ceotenure", the salary changes by a multiplicative factor of $e^{b1}$.
2. I think it should be the same unit as the dependent variable, so probably "log-dollars".
3. b1*ln(sales) changes to b1*ln(sales+1), and this isn't free from the current level of sales, so an interpretation of the regression coefficient is not easy here.
4. Profits may be negative. (Loss!)

Comment: A unit increase in $\ln(\text{sales})$ is the same as multiplying $\text{sales}$ by $e$. More typically we'd examine the effect of say a $1\%$ or $10\%$ increase in sales ($\ln(sales) + \ln(1.01)$ for the log variable, for example) as being more interpretable.